Unable to set "12:00" time in the iOS simulator
Works:
xcrun simctl status_bar "iPhone 15 Pro Max" override --time "12:01"

Fails:
xcrun simctl status_bar "iPhone 15 Pro Max" override --time "12:00"

Error:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Simulator device failed to complete the requested operation.
Invalid argument
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
        Invalid, non-ISO date/time string
        Invalid argument

I also tried 00:00 and 24:00 but none of them worked.

Also tried with xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "11:00" and got the same error. But xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "11:01" works! Simulator Version 16.0 (1038), macOS Version 15.0.1 (24A348).
